# Code structure, a methods should only do one thing

Tags: c#, structure

I am having a bit following the "a method should only do one thing"

I have a car text file, and if it contains even one BMW I want to set isValid to true, but while I am going through the text file anyways I thought I would also populate two list  high end models(M3,M5 etc) and lower model (335, X3 etc).

I know that  method should only do one thing, but it seems so convenient for it to also populate the lists. Here is what I have:

```
private bool hasBMWegments()
{
   foreach (ClassLib.CarSegment carElement in CarSegmentFactory.ContainsCar("BMW"))
   {
     isValid = true;
     if (carElement.Class.IndexOfAny(lowerModels) == 0)
     {
        lstOlderSegment.Add(carElement.ElementNumber);
     }
     if (carElementClass.IndexOfAny(upperModels) == 0)
     {
        lstNewerSegment.Add(carElement.ElementNumber);
     }
   }
   return isValid;
 }
```

Should I just create a method that performs the foreach check again? Or should I create another method inside that method (I would think that would be messy, and wouldn't related to the method name)

**edit: sorry working with framework 2.0**

Comment: How about a `ParseFile` method that parses the file, and writes class-level variables that includes the list and a bool stating if there is a bmw?

Comment: That is a pretty good way of looking at it, initialize everything right from the start. That is sort of what I am doing now, I am trying to set the list and the bool stating if there is a bmw.

Comment: A method's name should indicate what the method will do. If I call a method called `hasBMWegments()`, it had better not go adding values to some list somewhere! What if I called the method in two different places?

Comment: Ah yes, I guess I was thinking that if I set isValid, I wouldn't have to call that method again as I could just check the isValid or the list wherever (saving some time, but I guess those .00001 I save would be better if the code was cleaner)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find that code to be a mess compared to this:

```
private IEnumerable<ClassLib.CarSegment>
    GetModels(IEnumerable<ClassLib.CarSegment> segments, string modelID)
{
    return segments.Where(x => x.Class.IndexOfAny(modelID) == 0);
}

// ...

var bmwSegments = CarSegmentFactory.ContainsCar("BMW").ToArray();

bool isValid = bmwSegments.Any();
var olderModelSegments = GetModels(bmwSegments, lowerModels);
var newerModelSegments = GetModels(bmwSegments, upperModels);
```

This code is obviously correct at a glance.  The other code makes you look twice at the loop to figure out what's going on.

Comment: It is a mess :( trying to write clean code, but it just seems messy.

Comment: Then I would write `GetModels` with the same functionality, but with a loop instead.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like all you're doing is setting `isValid` to true on the first pass through the `foreach`. So all `isValid` really means is "is there at least one element?".

In which case you do not need to iterate twice. You can use [`Any()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx) to do the valid check:

```
bool IsValid(IEnumerable<CarSegment> elements)
{
    return elements.Any();
}

void PopulateSegments(IEnumerable<CarSegment> elements)
{
    foreach(var element in elements)
    {
        //add to lists
    }
}
```

Comment: isValid means that there is at least one element(which is a bmw, as there could be many other types of cars), that is correct

Comment: Even without Linq, you should be able to just check if the size of the array is greater than 0.